# Есть ли возможность вызывать функции с делегата по одной?

Tags: c#

```
        Action  D_For_reproduct_Functions;

        D_For_reproduct_Functions += ReproductExp;
        D_For_reproduct_Functions += ReproductArcSin;
        D_For_reproduct_Functions += ReproductNormal;
        D_For_reproduct_Functions += ReproductLaplasa;
        D_For_reproduct_Functions += ReproductReley;
        D_For_reproduct_Functions += ReproductVeibula;
```

Мне нужно что-то вроде такого

```
        for (int i = 0; i < D_For_reproduct_Functions.Length; i++)
        {
            D_For_reproduct_Functions[i]();

            KSKolvogorov();

            //и тут в будущем KSPirsona
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы можете разобрать ваш делегат на составные части при помощи `GetInvocationList()`. Вот пример:

```
Action combined = () => Console.WriteLine("Func 1");

combined += () => Console.WriteLine("Func 2");
combined += () => Console.WriteLine("Func 3");

var actions = combined.GetInvocationList().Cast<Action>();
foreach (var a in actions)
{
    a();
    Console.WriteLine("-----");
}
```

---

Но раз вам такое понадобилось, возможно, вы делаете что-то неправильно. Думаю, вам реально вместо `Action  D_For_reproduct_Functions` нужно `List<Action> D_For_reproduct_Functions`, и ваш код будет иметь вид

```
List<Action> D_For_reproduct_Functions = new List<Action>();

D_For_reproduct_Functions.Add(ReproductExp);
D_For_reproduct_Functions.Add(ReproductArcSin);
D_For_reproduct_Functions.Add(ReproductNormal);
D_For_reproduct_Functions.Add(ReproductLaplasa);
D_For_reproduct_Functions.Add(ReproductReley);
D_For_reproduct_Functions.Add(ReproductVeibula);

for (int i = 0; i < D_For_reproduct_Functions.Count; i++)
{
    D_For_reproduct_Functions[i]();
    KSKolvogorov();
}
```